# How to return duplicates if IN (...) has duplicates?

Tags: postgresql, where

I have a list containing `1, 1, 2`.

I am using it in a query like this:

```
SELECT A.* FROM A WHERE id IN (1, 1, 2)
```

The output is this:

```
id
---
1
2
```

I want the results to be like this:

```
id
---
1
1
2
```

How can I achieve that?

Comment: The `IN` clause is simply used to test if the value you're looking for is found in the list of values specified. It doesn't matter if the current value is found in that list once, twice, or 57 times - it will simply match the current value once.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with a `JOIN`:

```
SELECT a.* 
FROM a 
  JOIN 
    ( VALUES (1), (1), (2)
    ) AS p (id)
  ON a.id = p.id ;
```